# IndexedDB maximum key value in a key-value storage?

Tags: google-chrome, indexeddb

I am writing an application that refreshes **indexedDB** storage on each reload and generates a new set of key-value pairs on the database. The key value gets incremented each time since I am using **objectStore.clear()** before writing new key-value pairs.

1. What is the maximum value I can get to?
2. Is there a way to reset it to start from 1 again?

I know deleting the object store is one approach for this but the application is a time-sensitive operation and deleting takes some time to complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specification for this is at: https://w3c.github.io/IndexedDB/#key-generator-construct. The maximum value is 2^53 (9007199254740992). As the spec notes:

> As long as key generators are used in a normal fashion this limit will not be a problem. If you generate a new key 1000 times per second day and night, you won’t run into this limit for over 285000 years.

There is no way to reset the key generator for an object store.